# ASP.Net 6 No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've been trying to set up roles and users in startup.cs.  I now have the roles working but users just won't work producing "No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager'".  I've spent half a day going through the solutions given on stackoverflow and other sites including the examples on learn.microsoft.com and I get no closer to a solution.  I've taken out all the additions I've tried, which failed and got back to this where the roles work but not the users.
ApplicationDBContext looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<BOAPUser>
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
: base(options){}

public virtual DbSet<IdentityUser> BOAPUser {  get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);}
```

Startup.cs has:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<BOAPUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

with the place where it breaks:

```
using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
{
var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was.  The line that cause the problem should read

```
var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

and not

```
var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```